# Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, web, webpack

I'm building a React project on Cloud9, when I entered 'npm start' in terminal, I got error message like this:

```
./node_modules/fetch-blob/index.js 47:2
Module parse failed: Unexpected character '#' (47:2)
File was processed with these loaders:
 * ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib/index.js
You may need an additional loader to handle the result of these loaders.
| const _Blob = class Blob {
|   /** @type {Array.<(Blob|Uint8Array)>} */
>   #parts = [];
|   #type = '';
|   #size = 0;
```

Does this have something to do with 'node-fetch'? I did not meet the error until I installed 'node-fetch' and used it.

Comment: Any idea what the version of Node is?

Comment: Anything less than 12 won't understand those private fields - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/Private_class_fields#browser_compatibility

Comment: If you're using babel you need to enable [private-property-in-object](https://babeljs.io/docs/en/babel-plugin-proposal-private-property-in-object) either via setting preset-env to ES2022 or using the standalone plugin, though node-fetch is a node only module and should not be bundled via webpack to begin with, so maybe take another look at your includes